# How do I break out of this forech loop correctly C#

Tags: c#

Im new to programming and can´t seem to solve how to break out of my foreach loop correctly. The game is darts and should end when a player hits 301 points or more. Right now it doesn't end on 301, I only get it to end on 302 and for some reason it loops back to the first player. Please look at attached png for result.

[Result of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDeKv.png)

I am attaching the code that I believe causes the problem.

Feedback would be greatly appreciated! :)

Methods that are placed in my class **Game**.

```
  public void Playgame()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the dart-simulator!");
        Console.WriteLine("The game ends when a player reaches 301 points or more!");       

        int arrowOne;
        int arrowTwo;
        int arrowThree;
        int winningScore = 301;
        int total = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Add number of players: ");
        int numberOfPlayers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write name of player: ");
            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            AddPlayer(playerName);
        }

        do
        {

            foreach (var player in player_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} turn. Write a number between 0-20", player);
                arrowOne = PlayerScore();
                arrowTwo = PlayerScore();
                arrowThree = PlayerScore();
                player.Add_turn(arrowOne, arrowTwo, arrowThree);
                total = player.Calculatepoints();

                if(winningScore <= total)
                {
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        while (total <= winningScore); 
        {

            Console.WriteLine("We have a winner!");

            foreach (var player in player_list)
            {
                player.Print_Turns();
            }
        }
    }
```

Second method for adding player score.

```
    public int PlayerScore() 
    {
        int result;
        do
        {
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result))
            {
                if (result > 20 || result < 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Only write a number between 0-20!");
                    result = 0;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect number was given."); 

        } while (result == 0);

        return result;
    }
```

Two other methods placed in my class **Player**

```
        public void Add_turn(int arrowOne, int arrowTwo, int arrowThree) 
    {
        turn_list.Add(new Turns(arrowOne, arrowTwo, arrowThree));
    }
    public int Calculatepoints() 
    {
        int total = 0;
        foreach (var turn in turn_list)
        {
            total = total + turn.Get_Score();
        }
        return total;
    }
```

And one method placed in my class **Turns**

```
       public int Get_Score() 
    {
        int totalt;
        totalt = turnOne + turnTwo + turnThree;
        return totalt;

    }
```

Comment: This is a great opportunity to begin familiarizing yourself with a debugger.  Using a debugger you can step through the code line by line as it executes, observing the runtime behaviors and changing values of your variables.  Since you've narrowed the problem to "breaking out of the foreach loop", start your focus there.  When you step through the code in a debugger, what specifically happens that you don't expect?

Comment: Adding to what David said, ask yourself what a `do-while` loop does and what it means to have a `foreach` inside of a `do-while` (also, the curley brackets after the while don't make sense. They don't do any harm either, but you might run into scoping issues later on if you try to add more code). EDIT: And while we are at it, `<` and `<=` are two different things. :)

Comment: Thanks alot for replying so fast you guys! I will get on it immediately :)

Comment: I have been going through the debugger alot of times trying to figure out what causes the problem, and is not really sure. What catches my attention is the `foreach`. Does it repeat itself because there are two `var` in the `player_list`? But why does it use the same player twice? I understand the comparison operators to some degree :) `<` (less than) `<=` (less than or equal), am I using them wrong? Or is it the varibel `total` the problem, that it contains arrowOne, arrowTwo, arrowThree but temporary?

Comment: Guys I think I found solution! Please take a look if you think someting is incorrect :) Thanks for the hints!

Comment: I have rolled back the edits to your question. Solutions belong in a separate answer post, please do not edit them into the question.

Comment: Sorry! First time user and I didn't read the guideline. Thanks for the info!